# change selected index of repeater on click of button

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have 2 panels : left panel and right panel.

- Left Panel - contents of a book...
- Right Panel - consists of the content

User select any topic from left panel and display its content in right panel. For left panel I'm using repeater control. On right panel I have 2 button : next and previous.

My question is : How could I make the topic on the left panel selected when user clicks the next or previous buttons?

Comment: Yes that would have to be handled, but what is your question?

Comment: HOW TO CHANGE THE SELECTED INDEX OF THE REPEATER

Comment: `Repeater` don't have a `selectedindex` are you sure you use a `Repeater`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a repeater use the [ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx).  This is basically a repeater with some extra functionality including the ability to set the `SelectedIndex` property.